# Formik: prevent touching fields (do not mark as .touched) on Submit

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a situation where I need to prevent Formik from marking as `.touched` my fields when I Submit. `.touched` should be set when I touch a field, but clicking Submit should reset `.touched` to `{}`. I read in the docs that

> Before submitting a form, Formik touches all fields so that all errors
> that may have been hidden will now be visible.

I have my own custom `isInvalid=` definition and my own `submitClicked` variable that I track myself, so I need to turn off or reverse this behavior. I want `errors` populated, but I want `touched` to be empty (reset) after clicking Submit.

I was thinking of calling `setTouched({})` somewhere, but I need an event that tells me validation has completed. I also don't know where to insert it; I can't call it from a custom `useEffect` that watches `submitClicked`.

```
<Button type="submit"
        onClick{() => {
            // my own var.
            setSubmitClicked(true);
            // If I call setTouched({}) here, it does nothing. It gets overridden after Form Submit
            setTouched({});
        }} Submit
</Button>
```

also, can't really do it in a `useEffect`, I don't have access to Formik here and it's a mess to implement,

```
useEffect(() => {
    someFormikContext.setFieldTouched({}); // hard to get Formik Context here
}, [submitClicked]);
```

Are there any simpler solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset form on submit ,

```
onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {

  // do your stuff 
  resetForm();

}}
```

This will reset your form errors / touched , hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you but I need to keep `errors`. I should only reset `touched`.

Comment: then your approach i correct, if its not work it means there must be another issue, can you provide live code example with this issue it may easy to solve this